# Batch scripting - Rewrite an output

Tags: batch-file, scripting, url-rewriting, output

is there a way to rewrite an output using batch script?

```
C:\>icacls c:\amd | find/i "BUILTIN"
c:\amd BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
       BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
```

How can I obtain just the users/groups without the extras so it would look like below?

```
BUILTIN\Administrators
BUILTIN\Users
```

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)…

Answer (score 0):

`set` has a method to replace everything from the beginning until (including) a defined string: `set "var=*word=word"`
Because this doesn't work with a metavariable ("for-variable"), we have to assign each line to a "normal" variable, then replace "everything from the beginning to including `BUILTIN`" with `BUILTIN`, then just echo the first token of the rest delimiting by the colon.

Obviously, the output of `icalcs` is language-dependent, so replace `VORDEFINIERT` with the proper word in your Windows Language (`BUILTIN` in English):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "folder=C:\tmp"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('icacls %folder% ^|find "VORDEFINIERT"') do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for /f "delims=:" %%b in ("!line:*VORDEFINIERT=VORDEFINIERT!") do echo %%b
)
```

Comment: This is a very tricky (smart) script, I tried to figure out on what the 2nd loop is doing but I am not getting it. :)

Comment: It's explained in the second sentence of the answer. In the For loop set - everything `in (SET)`, It utilises the `Set` commands substring modification syntax to replace everything up to and including the supplied string with the value supplied. Read the output of `Set /?` in cmd.exe for more on that. The other part of the 'trick' is simply using the semicolon as a delimiter -

Comment: -  When no token option is used, the delim character acts as an end of line marker where the string in the for loops set is concerned. - so everything after and including the semicolon is disregarded. `for /?` in cmd.exe will tell you more about the syntax usages of the `For` Command

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, this helps me greatly!

Answer (score 0):

As I was playing with possible modifications. I've written the code below (thank you Stephen) so I could grab both BUILTIN and NT AUTHORITY entries.
It works even though the code isn't clean plus there's duplicates.
for /? has a lot to understand even though I tried to look up its references and samples elsewhere on the net.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "folder=C:\amd"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('icacls %folder% ^| findstr BUILTIN') do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for /f "delims=:" %%b in ("!line:*BUILTIN=BUILTIN!") do echo %%b
)

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('icacls %folder% ^| findstr "NT AUTHORITY"') do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for /f "delims=:" %%b in ("!line:*NT AUTHORITY=NT AUTHORITY!") do echo %%b
)
```

And this is the actual output.

```
BUILTIN\Administrators
BUILTIN\Users
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
```